# How can I share a correctly encoded url?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a shopping application in which I want to share the user's list through a `GET` parameter string in the url. Now the problem is that the list may contain spaces or umlauts. I tried to avoid errors by using Javascript's function **encodeURIComponent** and that's where a bug in my code occurs.

For debugging I logged the generated url in the console. Here spaces and umlauts are correctly encoded. But when I connect the url and the parameter, which I haven't touched since logging, the list is in its raw format with all illegal characters. Did I miss something really obvious or am I just using the wrong functions?

Here's my code:

```
function shareList() {
    let text = "";
    let boxes = getList(); //returns a list like [..., "Smoothie Purple;selectGetranke;0", "Smoothie Yellow;selectGetranke;0", ...]

    for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        text += boxes[i] + ",";
    }

    if (text.length > 0) {
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    }
    //forms the list into a string: ...,Smoothie Purple;selectGetranke;0,Smoothie Yellow;selectGetranke;0,...

    text = encodeURIComponent(text);
    text = "https://example.com/?lst=" + text;

    console.log(text); //logs https://example.com/?lst=...%2CSmoothie%20Purple%3BselectGetranke%3B0%2CSmoothie%20Yellow%3BselectGetranke%3B0%2C...
    sendWhatsApp(text); //sends the link https://example.com/?lst=...,Smoothie Purple;selectGetranke;0,Smoothie Yellow;selectGetranke;0,...
}

function sendWhatsApp(message) {
    window.location = "whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not aware of [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: You have to call `encodeURIComponent` on the result of `"https://example.com/?lst=" + text` and not (only) on the list of "boxes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I miss something really obvious or am I just using the wrong functions?

You did only *half* the job.

You encoded the `text` value for usage in *your* URL.

But then you are using your URL as the value of a parameter in another URL (the `whatsapp://send` one) - and *that* value you did not properly URL-encode.

```
window.location = "whatsapp://send?text=" + encodeURIComponent(message);
```